# Stepper motor control - full step not working

Tags: stepper-motor, uln2003

I am using a [ULN2003](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2001.pdf) to control a unipolar stepper motor from my PIC18F45K20. When I only connect one 12 V power cable (Red), the stepper motor works in full step, however, when I connect the other 12 V cable the motor stops and emits a high pitch noise and the outputs on all the PIC ports go low.

So, in conclusion, when I connect this one specific red cable, nothing works. I tried another stepper motor (same model), and the same happened. Any suggestions on what it could be?

My motor is similar to this one I found on the web:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/B1CC4C64ABBC7D3C86257BC70017B9E2

Your motor may be 4, 6, 8 wire and use of the wires may depend on the way you are configuring your driver (single ended or H-bridge for example). If you are using a ULN2003, it's highly likely you are using this type of connection with one common center connector connected to your supply for the coils:

[image]

You need to buzz out the wiring for your stepper motor and understand what wires connect to what coils.